# Sum two capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I need get two values from a string and sum them.

```
var text = 'SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00 13 5 10.517,81 0,00 10.517,81 0,00';
var reg  = new RegExp('SOC 01' +  '\\b.*?(?:\\d\\S*\\s+){3}(\\d\\S*)', 'i');
var reg2 = new RegExp('SOC 01' +  '\\b.*?(?:\\d\\S*\\s+){7}(\\d\\S*)', 'i');
var match = reg.exec(text);
var match2 = reg2.exec(text);
```

Output:

```
match[1] -> '1.667.621.57'
match2[1] -> '12.965.11'
```

(OBS: If you try run in the console the last number will have a comma, but in my node.js environment is a dot.)

I would like to know if i can create just one regex with two groups and sum them together.

The total should be `1.691.104,49`

I was trying to sum like this:

```
(+match[1]) + (+match2[1])

output: NaN
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the sum result is not `1.680.586,68`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to do something like:

```
Number(match[1].replace(/[\.,]/g, ''))
```

To strip out the `.`s and `,`s before summing the numbers.

If you need to get the number back into the same format, you can do something like this:

```
var total = Number(match[1].replace(/[\.,]/g, '')) + Number(match2[1].replace(/[\.,]/g, ''));

var result = String(total);
result = result.replace(/(?=\d{2}$)/, ',');
result = result.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
```

Which produces `1.680.586,68`.  I have the same question as stribizhev about how you are doing the summing.

<s>Here is the fiddle for the above example: https://jsfiddle.net/qw700fq9/</s>

**Here is the updated fiddle** - cleaned it up a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/rdu15ds3/

Also, adding the decimals back in was based on the answers to this question: [How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Worked! Thanks dustmouse!

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Now i just need replace the two regex with one capture group each for one regex with two capture group. Do you know how?

Comment: Do you still care about the decimals and comma?

Comment: What are you trying to capture in each group specifically?

Comment: The same result, i want pass the word SOC 01 and get the third and seventh value after words or numbers. The same result but with only one regex. Possible?

Comment: Can you show me what you've tried and I will try to help out.

Comment: unfortunately, i was trying to find something related that could help because i don't know where to start. But no problem @dustmouse, you already help me a lot!

Comment: Try this: SOC\s01\s(?:\S*\s+){3}(\S*)(?:\S*\s+){4}(\S*).

Comment: this wont work i think - var reg  = new RegExp('SOC\s01\s(?:\S*\s+){3}(\S*)(?:\S*\s+){4}(\S*).', 'i');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88714/discussion-between-dustmouse-and-amanda-ferrari).

Answer (score 0):

The regex is returning a string. You need to convert them to numbers before adding them.

```
function toNumber(n){
    return parseFloat(n.replace(/./g,'').replace.(/,/g,'.'));
}

toNumber(+match[1]) + toNumber(+match2[1]);
```

Comment: A possible typo: `s/is return/returns/`.