# Capture four numbers with one JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to capture four groups with only one regex.

I have this piece of text:

```
PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)
```

I want get the numbers after the keys:

```
PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING:
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS:
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS:
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS:
```

I can only use one regular expression, so I tried this approach:

```
var text = 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: 0.00 13º WORD WORD: 0.00' +
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';

var reg = new RegExp(SOME REGEX);
var match = reg.exec(text);

console.log(match[1], match[2], match[3], match[4]);
```

The result was `0.00 0.00 .00 .00`.

This is the regex that I was trying to use:

```
new RegExp('PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING:' + '\\b.*?(?:\\d\\S*\\s+){1}(\\d\\S*)(?:\\s?\\d\\S*\\s+){14}(\\d\\S*)(?:\\s?\\d\\S*\\s+){14}(\\d\\S*)(?:\\s?\\d\\S*\\s+){29}(\\d\\S*)(?:\\s?\\d\\S*\\s+){41}(\\d\\S*)');
```

The idea is to capture groups after words or digits that I can pass in.

But obviously this is not valid. How can I achieve my goal?

Sometimes the numbers change. They are not always `0.00`.

I need to explicitly pass the name of the word and the capture groups. Because the text is huge, I only showed part of it above.

I have this other regex that can do what i'm trying, but with another text:

```
var text = 'PREV SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00'
    var reg = new RegExp('PREV SOC 01' + '\\b.*?(?:\\d\\S*\\s+){4}(\\d\\S*)(?:\\s?\\d\\S*\\s+){5}(\\d\\S*)', 'i');
    var match = reg.exec(text);

console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
```

In this case I'm passing the word 'PREV SOC 01' and two capture groups, one to capture `1.667.621,57` and the other for `0,00`.

I need the same in this other text:

```
var text = 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: 0.00 13º WORD WORD: 0.00' +
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
```

I want to pass `'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOUT NOTHING:'` and choose what i want after digits and numbers.

Comment: I recommend using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) as place to try regexes,

Comment: Thanks @Ginden, i already know, i already try to learn a lot regex, but is very dificult the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by putting your keys into an array:

```
var keys = [
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING:',
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS:',
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS:',
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS:'
];
```

Now compile a regular expression that looks for a number after each key. You can use `[0-9.]+` to match a sequence of one or more characters in the class `[0-9.]`, which consists of the digits `0` through `9` and the `.` (period). That will suffice to match numbers that look like `0.00` and `314.159`.

Here is a regular expression that uses `[0-9.]+` to extract a number after each key:

```
var regex = RegExp(keys[0] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?' +
                   keys[1] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?' +
                   keys[2] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?' +
                   keys[3] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?', 'gi');
```

Note that `\\s+` matches one or more spaces after each key. You can change it to `\\s*` if you want to match zero or more spaces.

We are using `.*?` to match the shortest possible sequence of characters before the next key. The `'gi'` flags make the regular expression match globally (`g`) and without regard to case (`i`).

Before executing the regular expression, it's a good idea to replace all invisible whitespace with visible spaces. That's because `.*` does not match line-ending characters.

```
text = text.replace(/\s/g, ' ');
```

The snippet below demonstrates this approach with the sample text and keys that you gave in your question.

```js
function print(s) {
  document.write(s + '<br />');
}

var keys = [
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING:',
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS:',
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS:',
  'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS:'
];

// Compile a regular expression that looks for a number after each key.
var regex = RegExp(keys[0] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?' +
                   keys[1] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?' +
                   keys[2] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?' +
                   keys[3] + '\\s+([0-9.]+).*?', 'gi');

var text = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

// Replace newlines and other invisible whitespace with visible spaces.
text = text.replace(/\s/g, ' ');

// Find and display all matches.
var count = 0;
while (true) {
  var match = regex.exec(text);
  if (match === null) {
    break;
  }
  ++count;
  print('match ' + count + ': ' +
        [match[1], match[2], match[3], match[4]].join(' '));
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: 0.00 13º WORD WORD: 0.00
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00
PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD: 0.00
</div>
```

Comment: Hei Michael, here you are again haha. This is pretty good, but i need ask. Cant be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5x9wLuja/1/ ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What do you want to change? The way I assign the value of `text`?

Comment: Not that. Just use only one Regex and than pass 4 capture groups, just like in the fiddle. If is not possible that's ok.

Comment: Michael, maybe my less 50 points to help me achieve the last regular expression that i need to complete all? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465952/capture-two-groups-of-numbers-with-regular-expression-if-conditions-is-ok

Comment: I lost 15 points today because you unaccepted this answer. Is there a problem with the answer, or was it an accident?

Comment: Of course not hahaha! I think with was a miss click

Comment: Oof. That's a relief. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to capture a double number like `0.00`, this is the Regex `(\d.\d{2})` you need:

```js
var text = 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOUT NOTHING: 0.13 13º WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 3.85 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 9.02 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 5.21 WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';

var re = /(\d.\d{2})/g;

var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.write(m[0]+" ");
}
```

And this is a **[regex101 DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rV4iA8/1)**.

***Note:*** I used `document.write()` only for test, avoid using it.

## EDIT:

This is the new Regex `(PAY VALUES TO SUM - (?:WITHOU NOTHING|ADD. \d{2} YEARS): (\d.\d{2}))` of the second attempt to get what you need, I hope it is what you are looking for:

```js
var text = 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: 0.13 13º WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 3.85 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 9.02 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';
text += 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 5.21 WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD: 0.00';

var re = /(PAY VALUES TO SUM - (?:WITHOU NOTHING|ADD. \d{2} YEARS): (\d.\d{2}))/g;

var m;

while ((m = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
    re.lastIndex++;
  }
  document.write(m[0] + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this is a dinamic value, sometimes is not 0.00 @chsdk

Comment: I update my question, was missing some facts, sorry about that. I need explicitly pass the word that i need because the text is huge.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari I updated my answer, you can see that it captures differents numbers.

Comment: I need pass PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: and four capture groups, possible? @chsdk

Comment: @AmandaFerrari please take a look at my edit, I hope it's what you are looking for, I used this Regex: `(PAY VALUES TO SUM - (?:WITHOU NOTHING|ADD. \d{2} YEARS): (\d.\d{2}))`.

Comment: not really =/.. i need execute the regex to be a match, checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5x9wLuja/1/ this is what i'm trying to do

Comment: but with 4 matches and other text

Comment: What's the other text?

Comment: The other text is in the same text, but the same regex is not working =/. Checkout my update.

Comment: In that case this is the Regex you need: `PAY VALUES TO SUM .+ (\d.\d{2})`.

Comment: @AmandaFerrari What about the "g" flag? Example: `'aze rty'.match(/\w+/)` gives `["aze"]`, `'aze rty'.match(/\w+/g)` gives `["aze", "rty"]`

Comment: I think this is what you need `/PAY VALUES TO SUM .+ (\d.\d{2})/g`, take a look at this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rV4iA8/2).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my interpretation of your problem:

```js
var text = ''
+ 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)\n'
+ 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)\n'
+ 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)\n'
+ 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 0.00 (IGNORE THE REST)';

var re = /^PAY VALUES TO SUM - (?:WITHOU NOTHING|ADD\. \d+ YEARS): ([\d.]+).*$/gm;
document.write('<pre>' + text.replace(re, '$1').replace(/\n/g, ' ') + '</pre>');

// a little less specific

var re = /^PAY VALUES TO SUM - [^:]+: ([\d.]+).*$/gm;
document.write('<pre>' + text.replace(re, '$1').replace(/\n/g, ' ') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: guys, checkout this regex that i have http://jsfiddle.net/5x9wLuja/1/ i'm pushing two values after PREV SOCIAL 01, and i can say 'i want the value after 5 expressions'.. i need something like this

Comment: @AmandaFerrari This fiddle tells nothing more about what you want. Try to describe your needs better.

Comment: Ok, let me thing, give me a second, will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you only need the **1st occurrence** of each xx.xx number after the `:` in each line, as numbers can occur also after the 1st occurence.

If that is the case, then this is your regular expression:

`/^.*?:\s*([\d\.]+).*/gm`

And this is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/gT9tJ0/1

Comment: Checkout my update, i need explicitly pass the name and the capture groups, the text is huge, i just copy the interested party

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "explicitly pass the name and the capture groups".

Comment: I would like to pick up matches passing the word 'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING:' and then ( Take a value after so many words or digits) ( Take another value after so many words or digits ( Take another value after so many words or digits) ( Take another value after so many words or digits) . So i could look at the values ​​of [ 1], [ 2], [ 3] and [ 4] in a variable match. I know that is totally possible, but i don't know why, really.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:** you can use this short regex :`/PAY\s+VALUES\s+TO\s+SUM\s+[^:]+:\s*([\d.]+)/gmi`

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rV4iA8/3)**

```js
    var re = /PAY\s+VALUES\s+TO\s+SUM\s+[^:]+:\s*([\d.]+)/gmi; 
    var str = 'var text = \'PAY VALUES TO SUM - WITHOU NOTHING: 0.00 13º WORD WORD: 0.00\' +\ntext += \'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 50 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00\';\ntext += \'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 70 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD: 0.00\';\ntext += \'PAY VALUES TO SUM - ADD. 80 YEARS: 0.00 WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD: 0.00\';\n';
    var m;
     
    while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
            re.lastIndex++;
        }
        // View your result using the m-variable.
        document.write(m[1]+ ' ');
    }
```