# Capture two groups of numbers with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text:

```
'BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00 13 5 10.517,81 0,00 10.517,81 0,00 TOTAIS: 700 1.677.289,00 18.512,98 1.691.104,49 2.647,38'
```

The original format without replacing spaces and break lines is:

```
NUMBER    OTHER      OTHER        OTHER        BASE CÁL PREV SOC  BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 

01        672     1.653.806,09   18.512,98       1.667.621,57        2.647,38
07         23        12.965,11        0,00          12.965,11            0,00
13         05        10.517,87        0,00          10.517,81            0,00
TOTAL:    700     1.677.289,00   18.512,98       1.691.104,49        2.647,38
```

I want to extract information in the `BASE CÁL PREV SOC` column only in rows 01 and 07, but sometimes 07 doesn't exist. Row 13 will be ignored.

So I want to have a given phrase and matching groups in one regular expression.

Just to be clear, this data is inside a huge text, so the regex can't be generic. I have to explicitly pass a unique phrase that is close to the numbers. Here the chosen phrase is `'BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC'`. I just want get the numbers in 01 and 07 (although 07 will not exist sometimes), and ignore 13.

Just to be more clear, in the current example I expect the result to be 1.667.621.57 and 12.965,11.

I have this code:

```
var text = 'BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00 13 5 10.517,81 0,00 10.517,81 0,00 TOTAIS: 700 1.677.289,00 18.512,98 1.691.104,49 2.647,38';

var reg   = new RegExp('BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC' + '\\b.*?(?:\\d\\S*\\s+){4}(\\d\\S*)(?:\\s?\\d\\S*\\s+){5}(\\d\\S*)', 'i');
var match = reg.exec(text);

console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
```

I have to be sure that the number is 01 and 07, and if there is no 07, replace it with 00,00.

Is this possible?

Comment: `18.517,81` is not in your example data.  Do you mean `10.517,81`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying about 07 and 13. If you're only interested in 01 and 07, why should it matter whether there's a 13 or not? Don't you ignore 13 in all cases? In the example above, the value in 07 is 12.965,11. Isn't that what you expect to get?

Comment: Sorry, in my example is 12.965,11, 18.517,81 is in the 13 NUMBER, i want ignore if the NUMBER is 13 @RickHitchcock

Comment: Yes, but somethings the 07 will not exist and will only have 01 and 13, somethings will have only 13, somethings only 07.. so on so go @MichaelLaszlo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match a group that may not occur in the text, use the `?` modifier at the end of the group, like this:

```
'(?:.*?\\s+07(?:\\s+\\S+){3}\\s+(\\S+))?'
```

A complete regular expression in your case would look like this:

```
var re = RegExp('BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC' + 
                   '.*?\\s+01(?:\\s+\\S+){3}\\s+(\\S+)' + 
                '(?:.*?\\s+07(?:\\s+\\S+){3}\\s+(\\S+))?');
```

The first part of the regex definition is the phrase that you're looking for. Let's break down the second part:

- `.*?` matches zero or more characters of any kind (except line-terminating characters) as few times as possible
- `\\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters
- `01` matches the row number
- `(?:\\s+\\S+)` is a non-capturing group that matches one or more whitespace characters followed by one or more non-whitespace characters
- `{3}` makes the `(?:\\s+\\S+)` group match three times
- `\\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters
- `(\\S+)` captures one or more non-whitespace characters—this is the value we're looking for

The third part of the regex is similar to the second part, except it has `07` instead of `01`, and, crucially, it's enclosed in a non-capturing, optional group.

- `(?:` begins a non-capturing group
- `)?` ends the group and makes it optional

The important thing is the `?` after the closing parenthesis of the group. This `?` makes the whole group optional: it may match or it may not. It isn't strictly necessary for the group to be non-capturing. If we omitted the `?:` after the opening parenthesis, the regex would still work, except we would have to use `match[3]` to extract the value from the `07` row.

After executing the regular expression, a group that failed to match will have the value `undefined`. You can substitute a value of your choice like so:

```
var value07 = match[2] || '0,00';
```

In the following snippet, try replacing the `07` in the content with `08` to see what happens.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;

// Replace all whitespace with visible spaces.
text = text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

var re = RegExp('(?:.*BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC)+' +
                '(?:.*?\\s+01(?:\\s+\\S+){3}\\s+(\\S+))?' + 
                '(?:.*?\\s+07(?:\\s+\\S+){3}\\s+(\\S+))?');

var match = re.exec(text),
    value01 = match[1] || '0,00',
    value07 = match[2] || '0,00';

document.write(value01 + '<br><br>');
document.write(value07 + '<br><br>');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#content {
  color: #888;
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
NUMBER    OTHER      OTHER        OTHER        BASE CÁL PREV SOC  BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 

01        672     1.653.806,09   18.512,98       1.111.111,11        2.647,38
07         23        12.965,11        0,00          11.111,11            0,00
13         05        10.517,87        0,00          10.517,81            0,00
TOTAL:    700     1.677.289,00   18.512,98       1.691.104,49        2.647,38
  
NUMBER    OTHER      OTHER        OTHER        BASE CÁL PREV SOC  BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 

01        672     1.653.806,09   18.512,98       2.222.222,22        2.647,38
07         23        12.965,11        0,00          22.222,22            0,00
13         05        10.517,87        0,00          10.517,81            0,00
TOTAL:    700     1.677.289,00   18.512,98       1.691.104,49        2.647,38
  
NUMBER    OTHER      OTHER        OTHER        BASE CÁL PREV SOC  BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 

01        672     1.653.806,09   18.512,98       3.333.333,33        2.647,38
07         23        12.965,11        0,00          33.333,33            0,00
13         05        10.517,87        0,00          10.517,81            0,00
TOTAL:    700     1.677.289,00   18.512,98       1.691.104,49        2.647,38
</div>
```

Comment: Michael, if i'm not asking to much, can you break the regex for me? i'm studying them :)

Comment: Sure. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you Michael, you are very kind! It helped me a lot in these last days , I will be eternally grateful for your help. I finished all Regex I needed thanks to you. See you in two days.

Comment: I found a mistake in the regex. There has to be whitespace before the `07`, or else it could match at the end of a number that occurs before the `07` row. I've also reformatted the regex definition so that you can read it more easily. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I didn't test yet, i have two jobs, and just tomorrow i can test it! But thanks for that!!! :)

Comment: i don't want disturb you, but i test here and is almost ok. When the text have only 13, the regex will work and get the value, do you know why?

Comment: hm, i already know the problem. Can we force the regex to find the last BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC? I didn't know, but there is two in the text --'

Comment: Yes, you can do that by matching all occurrences of the phrase. Replace the first part of the regular expression with this: `'(?:BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC.*)+'` I have done so in the snippet to demonstrate that it now extracts values from the last section.

Comment: So you want to use the last section even if it doesn't contain an `01` row?

Comment: Please see my revised answer. Now the regular expression uses the last section regardless of what rows it contains. I'm also doing `value01 = match[1] || '0,00'` because now both values are optional. Updated fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/w7aL7xk0/ and http://jsfiddle.net/rref48mt/

Comment: Is everything fine now?

Comment: Michael, is absurd what the RegExp can do , I believe that is what is most powerful in the language , you agree? I am deeply in love with them and I really want to be able to make my own , it is extremely cool!

I was testing and it can take the same values ​​like this: http://jsfiddle.net/w7aL7xk0/1/

:OOOO hahaha

Comment: Regular expressions have their limits, but they can be powerful in the right situations. If you want to make your own regular expressions, keep practicing with small examples. You might like to try classic exercises such as extracting phone numbers or email addresses from a web page.

Comment: I'm better in Regex now, i can't do advanced but i'm really training a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = 'BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 01 672 1.653.806,08 18.512,98 1.667.621,57 2.647,38 07 23 12.965,11 0,00 12.965,11 0,00 13 5 10.517,81 0,00 10.517,81 0,00 TOTAIS: 700 1.677.289,00 18.512,98 1.691.104,49 2.647,38'
var reg = new RegExp("\\b(?:01|07)\\b(?:\\s+[\\d.,]+){3}\\s+([\\d.,]+)", 'g')
while( match = reg.exec(text) ) {
  console.log(match[1])
}
```

Comment: i can't use this @smathy, i need pass the word BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC =/

Comment: Why? What input can you get where my regex doesn't work for your purposes?

Comment: Because the text is huge, more than 300 pages, and will change, sometimes the regex can not work.. :/

Comment: it can't be used passing the word and breaking in match[1] and match[2]?

Comment: I don't really understand what impact you think the size of the text will have. If the field starts with a 01 or 07 by itself, and the value you want is the 4th space-separated value after that, then the above regex will work.  If it's not, then your question is missing that difference.

Comment: i really did not try use in the huge text, maybe it works really, sorry, i'm not very good with regex. But i need ask, is possible change the regex to make match[1] -> 01 and match[2] -> second value?

Comment: Not easily, no - because the 01 and 07 are optional.

Comment: You can have whatever you wanted inside that `while` block right? Like put a `var matches = []` before the `while` and then in block you could put: `matches.push(match[1])` and then after the `while` block you'll have `matches` with any match from the string in it.